# split strings by pattern without deleting pattern strings

Tags: r, string

For a pattern that starts with "pr" following with multiple "r", e.g., `pr, prr, pr...r.` I would like to split the non-pattern string and ALL pattern strings, without deleting the pattern. `strsplit()` does the job but deletes all `pr..r`. However, `stringr::str_extract_all` extracts patterned strings but non-pattern strings gone.

Is there a way to simply keep all strings but single out patterned strings?

```
x<-c("zprzzzprrrrrzpzr")

"z" "pr" "zzz" "prrrrr" "zpzr" # desired output; keep original character order
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit hacky but you can do one replacement to separate out the values you want with some separator character and then split on that separator character. For example

```
unlist(strsplit(gsub("(pr+)","~\\1~", x), "~"))
# [1] "z"      "pr"     "zzz"    "prrrrr" "zpzr"
```

which will work fine if you don't have "~" in your string.

Comment: Any clues why [this](https://regex101.com/r/4KeiG7/1) won't work in R (double-escaped of course and perl)?

Comment: @jay.sf. Good question. Not sure about that one. You were using it like `strsplit(x, r'{(?=pr)|pr+\K}',perl=T)`?

Comment: Yes, `strsplit(x, '(?=pr)|pr+\\K', perl=TRUE)`, looks different from the demo.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `stringr`. I would hope there is a way to make this a bit more concise.

- Locate the pattern with `str_locate_all()`
- Add one to all the end positions, so that we have split locations
- Add the start and end positions to the vector to split correctly
- Use the vectorized `str_sub()` to extract them all

```r
library(stringr)

x <- c("zprzzzprrrrrzpzr")

locs <- str_locate_all(x, "(pr+)")[[1]]
locs[,2] <- locs[,2] + 1

locs_all <- sort(c(1, locs, nchar(x) + 1))

str_sub(x, head(locs_all, -1), tail(locs_all, -1))
# [1] "zp"      "prz"     "zzzp"    "prrrrrz" "zpzr"
```